# Java Operations that will return the original value

Tags: java, algorithm, security

I am currently developing some security code. This code has a specific algorithm that may not be changed.
If someone were to decompile my code they were easily able to recreate the code and reverse engeneer it so that the person would be able to bypass that code. Even if it was obfuscated.
I talked about this problem with a friend who suggested that I add some pointless operations. Something like

```
var1 += 1;
var1 -= 1;
```

But I need some methods that are not easy to understand and the should not be very compution power consuming.
I am mostly working with long values so a few operation for Java long values would be really usefull.

#### As requested:

The environment are linux systems. The systems themselves are secure but there is a chance that someone might be able to get the compiled code.

The code will be used the authentificate a client. The server and the clients will use the same code. The main purpose of the code is the generate a authentification key that will be unique to every client and that will change frequently.

The algorithm has not been designed by me. I am simply the only one that can program it properly.

The job of the algorithm is basically to generate something like a hash. It uses several different inputs (Some of which are static and some of which change frequently) and then returns a String containing a hash the client will use to authentificate. The communication itself is secured with SSL. So a potential attacker would need to have to obtain the binary itself. Also some of the changing inputs are inside of the binary and some are not.

I am aware that obfuscation will not stop every attacker but I am sure if there is a decent obfuscation that most attackers will loose interest.
I know this for sure since we get attacked quite frequently by some beginner "hackers". Most of them barley even know Java and some are good enough to read simple obfuscated code. And these are the one we are trying to stop from understanding our algorithm. (I cannot give more details about the algorithm itself. For security reasons obviously).
The algorithm uses many longs. And I think it would really add a lot of time to the process of RE if there is tons of pointless code. (I hope this descibes the environment and the algorithm itself enough. If not please ask more specific questions)

Comment: Describe the environment you are working with (e.g. client / server?). What does your "security function" do? Where will the java code be?

Comment: Without more information it's difficult to say what the best approach is, but it's worth mentioning that obfuscation is a poor substitute for security.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of obfuscation. There is a market for automated bytecode obfuscation tools should you feel the need. Using one of those would probably be more effective and maintenance-friendly than manual obfuscation. However, be aware that **nothing** will stop determined reverse engineering when the program is accessible to the attacker (and sometimes even when not). Your security should be strong even when every detail of the algorithm and implementation are exposed.

Comment: Right.  Get a [byte code obufscator like ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/).  But nothing will save you from a determined attack.  If you need real security, better to [use the Java crypto package.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/package-summary.html)

Comment: I am planning on using ProGuard anyways. But even obfuscated code (like ProGuard does) can be read. Therefore I wish to add another layer of obfuscation that is not easy to bypass.

Comment: If your code can be run, it can be decompiled and reverse-engineereed.  There is absolutely nothing you can do about this.  Obfuscation only adds a few hours of extra work to the RE process.  It may not even be necessary to un-obfuscate the code to understand the algorithm.

Comment: You still have not explained the environment you are operating in ... nor what this "security algorithm" must do. Depending on what it is doing, you may want to consider multi-factor security.

Comment: This is just an insane idea, but what about implementing your algorithm in another language like C and providing the compiled libraries only, then just consuming the method through JNI? It is more work to do and impacts performance as well but may apply for your security concern.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza This is a fairly good idea. Sadly I am not very experienced with C. But I'll keep that idea in mind for the case that we still experience successfull attacks.

Comment: Java is a not a machine code language. Java decompiles beautifully. There is absolutely nothing you can do to prevent this. Any code that the client can access cannot be trusted. Think of another approach - an authentication service is a common solution.

Comment: Don't roll your own crypto to begin with. Use a library implementation of a well-known cryptographic hash instead.

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do will never be anything other than security through obscurity.  As far as client identity goes, there's really nothing you can add to the security provided by SSL.  Just generate sufficiently random ID on the client (like a UUID) and store it securely on the client.  You don't even gain much, if anything, by changing this ID frequently.

Comment: The general principle is that you should assume that the attacker knows the design, which cannot be easily changed, and use a secret key instead to secure it, which can be easily changed - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle - this also protects you from accusations that you have leaked the design if the system appears to have been broken, and it makes it easier to have the design independently reviewed for errors.